# php json_encode trailing zeros should not be removed

Tags: php, json, stm32f4

I have somewhat interesting case. We have embedded devices out there, pushing JSON data to our server. We use a checksum for data in sending, so device calculates the checksum over out payload and then sends a JSON data POST message.

When there are no decimals with trailing zeros, we are just fine. However, if we encounter a key with `double`/`float` value we are in trouble. We cannot use `%g` formatter on the device (STM32) so we need to do stuff like `%1.5i` to get the decimal points sent to server.

```
{
    "key":"emXOlXEBv9",
    "data":[
        "key_with_trailing_zeros":12.200,
        "time":"2017-12-22 19:35:41"}
    ],
    "csum":"XXX"
}
```

So now device calculates checksum over the `key` and `data` properties. When we send it to server and dump it after `json_encode` we get:

```
{
    "key":"emXOlXEBv9",
    "data":[
        "key_with_trailing_zeros":12.2,
        "time":"2017-12-22 19:35:41"}
    ],
    "csum":"XXX"
}
```

Although the data value can be used by our system a-ok , the checksum fails as the string buffer used to calculate the checksum is somewhat different.

Without magic tricks I cannot use `%f` or `%g` on the device so, so what options I have, turn all fields to string and read the numeric value at server or is there some magic bullet I have not found yet?

Comment: Can you post a minimal code example of your problem?

Comment: Since `"key_with_trailing_zeros":"12.200"` will also make the checksum fail, I think you're out of luck with `json_encode()` and you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: if trailing zeroes like that are important then you should be encoding the data as a *string*, not a float.

Comment: There is an extra `}` right after the `time`. I don't think that's on purpose, so yeah... I know this doesn't solve the problem, but just in case.